# NativeScript virtualScroll in huge list

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Beforehand I was using Ionic for my cross platform apps. When using Angular repeat, there was performance and memory issues in huge lists.

But ionic has a feature called `virtualRepeat` (or `collection-repeat` in v1.x). But it has lots of bugs and is not usable.

Is there such a feature in NativeScript? (It must not keep all elements alive in the list, and as user scroll change the list.) The same feature is available in [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html).

Also I took a screenshot video for performance demonstration. At first I have 20 items. Then for load more in scroll, I load a very huge list . Then, see the result:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=220FS2SqLqI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out, it uses virtulization. I ran this command:

```
tns debug android
```

Then I could be able to see the elements from chrome dev tools:

[image]

It uses only a few elements and while scrolling changes them.

Answer (score 3):

In Nativescript you will want to use ListView and not ngFor or other repeating techniques, Listview reuses view and reducing memory usage for big lists

Example

> ```
> <ListView [items]="myItems">
>    <template let-item="item">
>        <StackLayout>
>           <Label [text]='item.name'></Label>
>        </StackLayout>
>     </template>
> </ListView>
> ```

Link with docs/more examples:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html